# How to get Callback value into main method?

Tags: java, android

Is there any way to get callback value out into main method.

```
public List<Passion> downloadpassion()
  {

   fsDB.getPassionvalue(new OnDownLoadPassionList() {
       @Override
       public List<Passion> OnResult(List<Passion> passionList) {
           return passionList; //this is callback value 
       }
   });

    return passionList; //want passionList to pass here
}
```

Comment: What is this called from? What is the `main method` you refer to. This is very vague and we have no idea what's going on and what you're trying to do. Be clearer please.

Answer (score 0):

you should make a interface like this

```
public interface EventListener{
   void onListComplited(List<Passion> passionList)
}
```

and then add it as input for your function

```
public void downloadpassion(EventListener listener)
{

 fsDB.getPassionvalue(new OnDownLoadPassionList() {
   @Override
   public List<Passion> OnResult(List<Passion> passionList) {
         listener.onListComplited(passionList);
   }
 });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't `return` from a value within a callback.

Rewrite like this

```
public void downloadpassion(OnDownLoadPassionList onDownload) {
   fsDB.getPassionvalue(onDownload);
}
```

In your other method

```
main() {
    client.downloadpassion(new OnDownLoadPassionList() {
       @Override
       public List<Passion> OnResult(List<Passion> passionList) {
           // TODO: use this callback value
       }
   });
}
```